# code not working for other shp files

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

The question posed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033733/coloring-the-states-according-to-a-given-variable-using-ggplot/24035741?noredirect=1#comment37060096_24035741) , has been solved but somehow it is not working for a different shp file. Any idea why?
I have been trying with the shp file from [Coloring the states according to a given variable using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033733/coloring-the-states-according-to-a-given-variable-using-ggplot/24035741?noredirect=1#comment37060096_24035741) (the first link)

Code:

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
download.file("http://geocommons.com/overlays/204743.zip", destfile="204743.zip")
dir.create("ind")
unzip("204743.zip", exdir="ind")
india <- readShapeSpatial("ind/india_state.shp")
f_india <- fortify(india)
i <- sapply(india@data$NAME, function(x) agrep(x, data$Row.Labels, max.distance=.3, ignore.case=T)[1]) 
india@data$maj <- data$MAJORITY[i]
f_india <- merge(x=f_india, y=india@data, by.x="id", by.y="ID")
ggplot(f_india, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=maj)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="black")
```

Wrong output:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `merge` is probably messing with the order of the data. Try creating an index before it and reordering the data after the `merge`.

Comment: Just to confirm the above - the merge is definitely the problem. If you ggplot just the polygons of india, then f_india you see the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your merge is matching each row more than once, creating duplicate rows in the data. Additionally there is an ordering problem, and you lose polygons when there isn't a matching row.

Replace

```
f_india <- merge(x=f_india, y=india@data, by.x="id", by.y="ID")
```

with

```
f_india <- merge(x=f_india, y=unique(india@data), by.x="id", by.y="ID",all.x=T)
f_india <- f_india[with(f_india, order(id, order)), ]
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the output I get. The grey polygons are caused by mismatched names, but this is the only issue I can see.

[image: working map]

Comment: But something is wrong. The places where it should be blue/pink in color, its showing grey. This wasnt the problem with the previous code provided by @lukeA

Comment: Can I suggest you try again from scratch - it works perfectly for me. Some states do remain grey, but that's because the names haven't been matched, which is a different issue. You can't expect 'UP' to automatically map to 'Uttar Pradesh' without a bit more work.

Comment: Ya I have changed all the names according to the shp file .But still not giving the results as it should.

Comment: the codeis working but the longitude and latitudes are getting messed up.You can check for urself

Comment: but i think the problem is occuring before the merge in the sapply stage @lukeA

Comment: I've added the output I get. It looks fine to me, what is the issue?