# Code not running for shp file

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

This is an extension to he question that has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039621/code-not-working-for-other-shp-files/24040634#24040634).

The code when run

```
data <- structure(list(Row.Labels = c("Andhra Pradesh", "ASSAM", "Bihar", 
              "Chandigarh", "CHHATTISGARH", "DADRA & NAGAR HAVELI", "DAMAN & DIU", 
              "Delhi", "GOA", "GUJARAT", "Haryana", "Himachal", "Jharkhand", 
              "KARNATAKA", "KERALA", "MAHARASHTRA", "MANIPUR", "MEGHALAYA", 
              "MP", "Odissa", "PONDICHERRY", "Punjab", "Rajasthan", "TAMIL NADU", 
              "TRIPURA", "UP", "Uttrakhand", "WEST BENGAL"), LATITUDE = c(78.3, 
              91.5, 85.13, 76.79855, 81.63, 72.96667, 72.8064, 72.8064, 73.96992, 
              72.4, 75.95947, 75.95947, 85.33, 75.68481, 76.82739, 75.64087, 
              93.58, 91, 93, 77.21067, 79.82803, 75.5, 75.52, 88.4, 91.25, 
              91.25, 78.2, 88.24), LONGITUDE = c(17.200001, 26.09, 25.370001, 
              30.744196, 21.23, 20.266666, 20.25189, 20.25189, 15.384293, 23.030001, 
              29.017748, 29.017748, 23.35, 14.849231, 9.470736, 19.590844, 
              24.440001, 25.299999, 23.299999, 28.623932, 11.937899, 30.4, 
              26.549999, 27.200001, 23.5, 23.5, 30.110001, 22.34), MAJORITY = c("Yes", 
              "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
              "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
              "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No")), .Names = c("Row.Labels", 
              "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", "MAJORITY"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))

library(raster); library(ggplot2)
india <- getData('GADM', country="IND", level=1) 
f_india <- fortify(india)
i <- sapply(india@data$NAME_1, function(x) agrep(x, data$Row.Labels, max.distance=.3, ignore.case=T)[1]) 
india@data$maj <- data$MAJORITY[i]
f_india <- merge(x=f_india, y=unique(india@data), by.x="id", by.y="ID_1",all.x=T) 
f_india <- f_india[with(f_india, order(id, order)), ] # to prevent this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039621/code-not-working-for-other-shp-files
ggplot(f_india, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=maj)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour="black")
```

The graph comes out to be:[image: India]

The same code when being run on the shp file (the first link from [here](http://geocommons.com/searches?query=india+states))

comes out to be:
[image]

Which is wrong!! Kindly help to get me the first map using the shp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is trying to match on ID values and row numbers and that is fragile. I doubt those ID values are 'official' identifiers you can rely on to match across data sets. The USA has a set of "FIPS" identifiers that you can use to match states and counties etc across correctly coded data sets, but I see no such thing here. The gadm data has a PID which might be something, but there's no matching PID in either your dataset or the shapefile you pointed us to.

The only thing you can rely on is the region names, and those have variations that make exact matching hard.

Also, don't try the fortify stuff until you've got ONE extra column in your map object with the variable you want to map. At least then you can plot that and check it's all in the right place.

Once you've got columns that agree with each other in your map and your data, then its as easy as:

```
require(rgdal)
ishape = readOGR(".","india_state")
ishape$MAJORITY = factor(data$MAJORITY[match(tolower(ishape$NAME), tolower(data$Row.Labels))])
spplot(ishape, "MAJORITY")
```

[image]

There's a lot of blank areas where the names don't match, even after I've flattened everything to lower case. Fix them up and repeat. Mapping with ggplot is then more straightforward since the thing you want to map is already in the map data.

You can see which ones aren't matching with:

```
> unique(as.character(ishape@data[is.na(ishape$MAJORITY),"NAME"]))
 [1] "Daman(Daman&Diu)"    "Sikkim"              "Himachalpradesh"    
 [4] "Jammu & Kashmir"     "Rajastan"            "Madhya Pradesh"     
 [7] "Uttaranchal"         "Uttar Pradesh"       "Mizoram"            
[10] "Arunachal Pradesh"   "Nagaland"            "Orissa"             
[13] "Laksha Dweeps"       "Andaman and Nicobar"
```

Correct those (Rajastan/Rajasthan etc) and you'll get a fuller map.